# How to convert Liferay PortletPreferences to JSR-168 PortletPreferences?

Tags: liferay, portlet, preferences

I'm looking for simple approach for converting the

```
com.liferay.portal.model.PortletPreferences
```

to

```
javax.portlet.PortletPreferences
```

Comment: In order to work with JSR PortletPreferences you just access them through the API, no? What's the situation you're in so that you need to worry about this in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

```
public javax.portlet.PortletPreferences convert(long companyId, com.liferay.portal.model.PortletPreferences obj) throws Exception {
    long ownerId = obj.getOwnerId();
    int ownerType = obj.getOwnerType();
    long plid = obj.getPlid();
    String portletId = obj.getPortletId();
    return PortletPreferencesLocalServiceUtil.getPreferences(companyId, ownerId, ownerType, plid, portletId);
```